Unlocking and mounting Linux SSD disk
Today when I turned on my laptop the OS couldn't start. After the BIOS loaded it was stuck in an infinite loop. The system couldn't boot SSD disk.
So I installed temporary OS Ubuntu 22.04 on another drive to mount my bootabole encrypted SSD disk.
This is not LUKS encryption. The temporary OS recognizes the  SSD disk. On the left side there are bpool and rpool icons. But I can`t see the contents.
How can I mount encrypted SSD disk with command line so I can copy the data?





udisksctl unlock -b /dev/sdb

The response is:
Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb is not an encrypted device.

I was ale to solve this problem by plugging only the encrypted SSD drive by USB witch start normally. I passed pasword and was eable to loging to the system! I already backup my data. Thank you so much for helping me!
